# Debugging stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio (using context menu debug stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, debugging, stored-procedures, ssms

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701(v=vs.103).aspx

From the above link, it seems it is possible to debug a stored procedure in SSMS.

I am accessing a SQL Server instance using SQL Server authentication with admin privileges. I want to debug a stored procedure in SSMS, but I don't get that option.

Somebody told me that it works only with Windows authentication (while connecting to the database). I don't know to what extent this is true.

What are the prerequisites for allowing to debug a stored procedure? Because in deployment, stored procedure might have 50k lines and it would be hard to debug by print selective statement to get the clue and all (workaround).

Following are true in my case:

1. SSMS is professional edition.
2. SQL Server user for accessing is admin user

(IMHO, there needs to be a way to debug a stored procedure with SQL Server authentication mode too).

So, I would really appreciate, If someone can take me through that process

Comment: I can do it with login/password in stead of windows authentication. But I cannot get it to work from the SSMS installed on my own computer, I have to do remote desktop to the computer Sql Server is installed, and when I use the SSMS on that computer it all works

Comment: I understand and I have heard somany things like what are the prerequsities. Is there any microsoftguidline

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can debug... I'm doing it right now with SQL Server 2016 and SSMS 17.6.

I'm using Windows Authentication.

Check the following printscreen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was firewall. In mostly companies Window's firewall is disabled and some other tools such as symtanec or third party application firewall are used.

It is tough for IT security to turn on or set those extra filter for SQL Server.

So, I had to screw my head everyday with same crap

Answer (score -1):

This is not available in SSMS. You need SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to use the debug in stored procedure. You can download it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt).

You can connect as Windows Authentication or SQL Authentication. Just make sure you have proper read/write access to view and execute the stored proc in Development Environment. **Avoid using this tool in Prod.**

[image]